# Delete asset and component with groovy in Nexus Sonatype

Tags: groovy, nexus, sonatype

We are using the latest release of nexus and I want the create a cleanup task.

I have a groovy script that runs over my iterable components list that I got from the transaction object.

Now I would like to find the asset to the component and then delete the asset and component.

My script looks like this:

```
// Get a repository
def repo = repository.repositoryManager.get('maven-releases');
// Get a database transaction
def tx = repo.facet(StorageFacet).txSupplier().get();
// Begin the transaction
tx.begin();

def components = tx.browseComponents(tx.findBucket(repo));

// retention date
def retentionDate = new DateTime();
retentionDate.minusDays(1);

components.each{comp ->
    def lastComp = comp.group() + comp.name();
    def lastModDate = comp.lastUpdated();

    if(lastModDate.isBefore(retentionDate)) {
        // here -----------
        // tx.deleteAsset(<asset>)
        // -----------------
        tx.deleteComponent(comp);
        log.info("${lastComp} deleted!");
    }

    log.info("anz: ${assetCount} ${comp.version()} - ${lastModDate} - ${retentionDate}");
}

// End the transaction*/
tx.commit();
```

Is it possible to find the corresponding asset to the component?

Answer (score 1):

This was easy:

```
Asset asset = tx.findAsset(comp.entityMetadata.getId(), tx.findBucket(repo));
```